# Magento 2 products being added to incorrect categories

Tags: mysql, cron, magento2, product, categories

Every evening, some action is adding a certain set of products to several categories, that they should not be added to. They always seem to be same products, and are always added to the same categories.
I have been attempting to find the action responsible. The site was orignally migrated from Magento 1.

There is also an issue when try to use the product selector grid for some categories. Complaining about urls for specified store already exists. Unsure if this is related. this is something being looked at seperately.

**- Can I monitor certain DB tables, and log a stack trace when certain tables are modified? EG catalog_category_product, when certain category/product IDs are added?**

What I have tried:

1. I re-created one category, it kept its original url. the issue persisted. I then changed its url, the issue for that one category stopped.
2. I have searched the code and database for references to the products/categories being added(Ids, Names, Urls), but cannot find anything that seems relevant.
3. I have been turning off certain import actions, one each day to see if the issue stops. The issue persists.
4. If I remove the products from the categories, and run actions such as indexing, they do not seem to be added.
5. I have checked the cron table/log...and do not see anything out of the norm being run

---

So what I am asking, is:

1. Can I monitor certain DB tables, and log a stack trace when certain tables are modified? EG catalog_category_product, when certain category/product IDs are added? Taking into account this may be updated via a query, and not just calling a model for the table.
2. How might I go about further debugging this issue, and find out what is adding products to these categories each evening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.